# Achievements indicator no longer showing number for rep change

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, top-bar, achievements-dialog

In the last hour or two I've gotten green notifications for rep changes, but they look like badge notifications because there's no number:

[image: screen shot with obligatory freehand circles]

I sometimes see this graphic appear for something less than a second and then be *replaced* (or overlaid?) by the number, but this stayed the same over time (a few minutes in the header, and I left the drop-down in the screen shot in place for several seconds).  This has happened a few times.

(OS 10.6, Firefox 31.0 and Chrome 36.0.1985.125, no known recent changes in add-ons.)

Edit: I just got a number-bearing notification on my Android phone (Chrome), but this bug is still showing in Firefox on my Mac.

Comment: Happened to me too, but as I got only +10 thought it might be a one time glitch.

Comment: I lost my 141 inbox notifications... :(

Comment: @Mysticial good chance you'll get the number back when the bug is fixed, so if you're into hoarding it, do not click the drawer! ;-)

Comment: *Leaves a comment so it can just be ignored, since it's also broken*

Comment: However mobile shows.

Comment: Web sockets are working just fine otherwise, *just* the global inbox and achievement boxes are affected.

Comment: Also affects comment notifications, not just rep change notifications: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239677/suddenly-not-getting-comment-notifications

Comment: I believe the [badge-page broke at the same time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239648/241497) ... related?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIeiO.png

Comment: @rolfl Unrelated.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Chat is different. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm deploying the fix. Should be live <s>in the next 20 minutes or so</s> now.

Comment: What happened to make this not appear? Something to do with redis?

Comment: @hichris123 Nah, just an errant CSS change. Reverted the commit and presto.

Comment: *needs someone to upvote some post to test out*