# Delayed in reputation notification

Tags: support, notifications, top-bar

I didn't get reputation changed notification in stackoverflow.com for one day(from morning to night) even after my reputation increases. After one day(today) I get the notification. Can it be ignored even if it takes so long time?

Comment: If you now do get the change, it was [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239641/achievements-indicator-no-longer-showing-number-for-rep-change). If you still don't get the number in real time, post comment on Anna Lear's answer and let her know the bug is still not 100% fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't a delay. Simply yesterday rep and inbox indicators weren't reflecting new notifications because of A Bug, but if you had clicked one of them you would have seen your new inbox or new rep changes. The bug [was fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239691/259214), so you can see notifications again.

Comment: My reputations have decreased by 15 and i haven't received any notifications yet.

Comment: @MairajAhmad You *never* receive notifications if your rep is decreased. Because SE wants us to notice only good things :)

Comment: But i think there should be notice for this also.

Comment: @MairajAhmad Can't do anything about it. Ask devs.

Comment: Where can i ask devs ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad Simply ask a new question (feature-request) saying that you would like downvotes to be reflected in the top bar.